# How can I extract two columns from a .txt file with python?

Tags: python, csv

I have done some calculation. I want to extract two columns from the data  and save them in another file with python.

This is what I've done so far: I saved the file as .txt and then wrote this script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

f = open('file.txt')

csv_f=csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:

     print row[1:3] # to get the second and third columns

f.close()
```

The problem is when I am running the script: I got this error: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I already know what the problem is because it shows all results in each row as on character in the list. How ever I don't know how to solve this problem to get them separately in a row.

This is two first rows of the file as an example:

```
Ene:   1    -0.429787341139E+03   -0.42979E+03   -0.59461E+01  4296   0.664E+00    0.167E+01
Ene:  2    -0.395935688219E+03    0.33852E+02   -0.43868E+01  4356   0.711E+00    0.928E+00
```

but this is what I got when I  use print row:

```
['Ene:   1    -0.429787341139E+03   -0.42979E+03   -0.59461E+01  4296   0.664E+00    0.167E+01']
['Ene:   2    -0.395935688219E+03    0.33852E+02   -0.43868E+01  4356   0.711E+00    0.928E+00']
```

I'd really appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: `open('path').split(' ')[1:3]`

Comment: The space like characters between the entries in file, are these tabs? That is `\t` or some counts of real spaces like ` `? You might give your csv reader an idea on the "dialect" i.e. which character separates the fields in a record (row). Than it is easy to read them in via csv module. Other wise it is best to read as text file and split via space. The proposal from @self does not work, as a file has no attribute split. A string when reading it in line by line would have that method(attribute though. Please indicate if tabs are separting in input. Thanks

Comment: They are real spaces and they were in the original output form my calculations, I just copied them.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the correct delimiter (default is `','`):

```
csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')  # if the file is tab delimited
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried these commands but It still put all elements in a row as one element in the list!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't require the use of the csv module

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as data: #using the with keyword ensures files are closed properly
  for line in data.readlines():
    parts = line.split(',') #change this to whatever the deliminator is
    print parts[0], parts[1] # parts[0] is the first column and parts[1] is the second column
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

f = open('file.txt')

csv_f=csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:

     print row.split(" ").[1:3] # to get the second and third columns

f.close()
```

Comment: This would work but doesn't use the full power of the csv module.